# electron will not load ssrs report

Tags: jquery, angularjs, node.js, reporting-services, electron

I added a link inside my html page in my Electron app that opens a SSRS report.

When I click the link, it tries to navigate but nothing renders. I clicked the developer tools and I am getting jquery errors.

[jQuery Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JECxq.png)

I've included jQuery in my dependency file as well as declared it in my reporting.js -- const {sql,$} = require('../dependencies');

Im using webviews within Electron..

Has anyone else tried or had this error and if so, can you help??

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.. I installed open (npm i open) and it will launch in a new window and render correctly